# How to type this symbol?

Tags: symbols

I would like to type the following character, which looks like a greater sign with two bars, but I don't know how. I have a link to the Wikipedia page as well as its image.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sori_(music)

[image]

Comment: `\newcommand*\sori{{\ooalign{$>$\cr\hidewidth$\parallel$\hidewidth\cr}}}`

Comment: do you check http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, if this symbol exist? if not, then you need to compose it ...

Comment: Do you need it as a math operator or a plain text symbol?

Comment: As this is a music symbol, do you need this to work with, say, Lilypond or musixtex? That might help to inform the answers that you might receive.

Comment: I was hoping this would be a common character so I could use it in non-LaTex environments as well (e.g. Google Doc, Word, Mathematica, etc). But I guess it is impossible.

Comment: @Miladiouss complain to the Unicode consortium, maybe while they're making other food Emojis they can add it.

Comment: i've received some information from the unicode people about how to pursue getting this added.  (it's not a math symbol, so i can't propose it directly.)  please get in touch with me via email (bnb at ams dot org -- i will delete this comment when i've heard from you) and i will share that information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\sori{\stackengine{1pt}{\ensuremath{>}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
  \scalebox{-1.3}[1]{\textsl{=}}}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
A\sori B
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A `picture` mode implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\newlength\sori@ht
\newlength\sori@wd
\newlength\sori@thin
\newlength\sori@thick
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsori}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\sharp$}%
  \setlength{\sori@ht}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
  \setlength{\sori@wd}{\wd\z@}%
  \setlength{\sori@thin}{\dimexpr\sori@wd/15}%
  \setlength{\sori@thick}{\dimexpr\sori@wd/6}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\sori@wd}%
  \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{\text@sori}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\text@sori}{%
  \begin{picture}(\sori@wd,\sori@ht)
  \roundcap
  \linethickness{\sori@thin}
  \put(4\sori@thin,0){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\sori@ht-2\sori@thin}}
  \put(11\sori@thin,2\sori@thin){\line(0,1){\dimexpr\sori@ht-2\sori@thin}}
  \buttcap
  \linethickness{\sori@thick}
  \polyline(0.13333,0.4)(0.86667,1.075)(0.13333,1.75)
  \end{picture}%
}
\providecommand{\textsharp}{\ensuremath{\sharp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textsharp\textsori

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand*\sori{\ifmmode\mathrel\fi{\ooalign{$>$\cr\hidewidth$\parallela$\hidewidth\cr}}}
```

With that command you can use `\sori` in text mode (in case you wanted to use it in text mode) and in case your intended use is in math mode it will give `\mathrel` spacing.

If you need it to scale in subscripts we can do that easily.

Comment: an ordinary `\parallel` will have both vertical bars with the bottom sitting on the same horizontal "baseline".  on the sori symbol. the bottom of the two bars follows the slant of the lower arm of the "greater than" sign.